# Downloading PDF's through Perl OLE iexplorer

Tags: perl, internet-explorer, download, ole

After doing a lot of research and still coming up with almost nothing I propose this challenge to you all.

I am trying to script an automated PDF downloader that has to be passed through a PAC file configuration.

I have tried LWP::UserAgent and assigned the PAC file to it and tried using it's get method, but this created a corrupted PDF file. Bare in mind I am passing it the URL that contains the PDF (i.e., http://www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf).

Modules like File::Fetch work, but will not go through the proxy which of course makes this a non-feasible solution.

A suggestion was made to use OLE and download using an Internet Explorer object, since IE has the proxy setting automatically configured it should be simple enough. After a few hours of research and playing around I could not find anything in the InternetExplorer.Application API that would allow me to download a PDF site like the one above.

I know I can do automated browsing with various modules, but my main thing is to pass a URL that contains a PDF and download it, the hard part is ensuring that this goes through the PAC file.

Any suggestions would be of great help!
Thanks Much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Win32::IEAutomation` if you need to automate IE but I'm sure there is no need in it for such simple task like you have.

Comment: I don't need to automate IE. I need to download PDF's from URLs. From what I saw there is no obvious option in Win32::IEAutomation in order to download these PDF's to a local directory